# Show/Hide Layer onclick inconsistencies

Tags: javascript, css

I have the javascript below, it shows and hides a layer when a button is clicked. However I have 2 of these installed on the same page and closing/opening does not work efficiently in that scenario

```
function setVisibility(id) {
    if (document.getElementById('button').value == 'Close') {
        document.getElementById('button').value = 'Open';
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('button').value = 'Close';
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';
    }
}

function setVisibility(id) {
    if (document.getElementById('button_2').value == 'Close') {
        document.getElementById('button_2').value = 'Open';
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('button_2').value = 'Close';
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';
    }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EadRvW

If you click on each Open button, you will see after one button is clicked, it takes 2 clicks for the other button to successfully open the layer. The same with closing them. Clicking alternately on each Open button, shows they don't respond as they should when clicked.

I am not sure what needs to be done to allow them to work together. They work fine when just 1 exists on the page. Does anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the same function (`setVisibility`) defined twice, so the first definition was replaced by the second one.

Setting your javascript like this fixes the problem:

edit: I prefer this version more, and I set it to change the button text as well:

```
function setVisibility(id) {
    var targetButton;
    switch( id ) {
    case "layer":
        targetButton = "button";
        break;
    case "layer_2":
        targetButton = "button_2";
        break;
    }
    if (document.getElementById(targetButton).value == 'Close') {
        document.getElementById(targetButton).innerHTML = 'Open';
        document.getElementById(targetButton).value = 'Open';
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById(targetButton).innerHTML = 'Close';
        document.getElementById(targetButton).value = 'Close';
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';
    }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JomBbm

Comment: Awesome @MikeWillis thanks. I added some more code in to make the layers close when you click off the layer, but that's not working. It worked with the old version of code I had (but I'm using your neater method now) and it doesn't seem to work http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyRqoz :\

Answer (score 1):

As [Mike Willis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29020051/2246380) has mentioned you have defined the same function twice and it is causing the issues and I understand that you want to change the button's label on click based on your code then you should change `innerHTML` instead of `value`.

```
function setVisibility(id) {
    if (document.getElementById('button').innerHTML == 'Close' && id=="layer") {
        document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = 'Open';
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    } else if (document.getElementById('button').innerHTML == 'Open' && id=="layer") {
        document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = 'Close';
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';
    } else if (document.getElementById('button_2').innerHTML == 'Close' && id=="layer_2") {
        document.getElementById('button_2').innerHTML = 'Open';
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('button_2').innerHTML = 'Close';
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';
    }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEVayq

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time help. The labels was my next task to tackle, but you guys sorted that too!